# Im having trouble with dynamic lists in SwiftUI. I cant get my list to update dynamically using a picker

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Basically as the title states. I have the picker called Ingredients and when I go into the list and click an element it should work as a button (or maybe not) and use the add function to append that element into the ingredients list which is a state variable which should then in turn update the list at the bottom and display its elements, but it doesnt. I have done other projects with a similar idea of an updating list but never with a picker. Any help appreciated. Also worth mentioning is that the TEST button works for what i want to achieve and the @ObservedObject can be ignored.

```
import SwiftUI

struct AddRecipe: View {
    @ObservedObject var recipe: RecipeFinal
    @State private var name = ""
    @State private var time = 0
    @State private var diff = ""
    @State private var ingredients = [String]()

    static var diffT = ["Easy", "Medium", "Difficult"]

    static var ingred = ["Onion","Salt","Oil","Tomato", "Garlic", 
"Peppers","Bread","Vinegar"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                TextField("Name", text: $name)
                Stepper(value: $time, in: 0...120, step: 15) {
                    Text("Time: \(time) minutes")
                }
                Picker ("Difficulty", selection: $diff) {
                    ForEach (AddRecipe.self.diffT, id: \.self) {
                        Text($0)
                    }
                }
                Button("TEST") {
                    self.ingredients.append("TEST")
                }
                Picker("Ingredients", selection: $ingredients) {
                    ForEach (AddRecipe.self.ingred, id: \.self) { ing in
                        Button(action: {
                            self.add(element: ing)
                        }) {
                            Text("\(ing)")
                        }
                    }
                }
                Section(header: Text("Ingredients")) {
                    List (self.ingredients, id: \.self) {
                        Text($0)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    func add (element: String) {
        self.ingredients.append(element)
    }
 }

struct AddRecipe_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AddRecipe(recipe: RecipeFinal())
    }
}
```

Comment: Does one ingredient show up, or none at all?

Comment: I'm thinking that the problem is that `Picker` is for a single selection, and as you passed it a `Binding` to your `ingredients` array, it is ensuring that only one ingredient is selected at a time

Comment: The problem may also be that the selection passed to the `Picker` is an array, when it should be an element.

Comment: I think the gist of it is that you shouldn't be using `Picker`, because that's not the functionality you're looking for — you just want how it looks (correct me if I'm wrong, but that's how I'm reading your question). I think you need to make your own view/composition of views that has the look you want, so that it has the correct functionality